# Embedded json object as String in java POJO

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

My service receive the following request:

```
@Data
public class InputRequest{
private Information info;
private String response;
}
```

I am trying to figure out what is the right way to represent the above in the form of JSON.

Note: `response` can be any jsonObject like

```
{
"country":"Canada",
"State":"Ontatio"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoping `service` you are referring to Rest service. If you are purely building using JAXRS specifications. Then it can be done easily by converting any Pojo to JSON using `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` API.

For instance, here MessageData is returning by Response will convert by JSON underlying container.

```
// pojo web service will return to service consumer
MessageData response = new MessageData();
response.setMessageId(msgId);

// return pojo with response code. 
Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).entity(response).build();
```

I've recently written an [article](https://medium.com/@faisal.qadeer/developing-rest-webservice-using-jax-rs-and-apache-tomee-9b3ad602d5e6) on creating and testing REST service using JAX RS specification with Apache TomEE. See if that can be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Data
public class InputRequest{
private Information info;
private Object response;
}
```

Unless there is some need to work with the string directly later if you map it to just an Object then it can work for both any single Object (including a String) or a multi-item Object like a List<> or Map<> or ....